# ConcatRelated function - use carriage return instead of comma/space as seperator

Tags: vba, ms-access, concatenation

What would I update in Allen Browne's ConcatRelated Function [Concatenate values from related records](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) to use a carriage return, instead of comma/space, as the separator?

Or... if that's complex... how would I use a space instead of comma/space?

Comment: According to this doc http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html, 
use the fifth argument to specify the separator to use between items in the string.

Comment: So if I only want that option but not the 3rd/4th arguements... do I simply 2 commas after the 2nd arguement? That's the part I couldn't figure out...

Comment: you can enter empty argument like this , "", "", CHAR(13)
unsure about CHAR(13), should be the carriage return

Answer (score 0):

Put in the below for the fourth and fifty variable. That ended up working.

```
,"",Chr(13) & Chr(10))
```